# Bootstrap Tooltips not getting called in Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Bootstrap is working fine on the site, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to get tooltips happening. Maybe I am not calling it right?

```
<div class="span3 app9downloadIcon downloadSectionItem" title="Download for App 9" id="' + appID + '" format="app9" appname="'+item.title+'"></div>'

//calling tooltip here
    $(app9downloadIcon).tooltip();
```

So basically `app9downloadIcon` is a div with a background image specified in the css. I want to hover over the image and have the tooltip appear with "Download for App 9". But it doesn't do anything on hover atm. BUT I change it to `$(app9downloadIcon).tooltip('show');` it indeed shows the tooltip, but it's static and visible the whole time.

Answer (score 2):

If this is the exact code, the jquery part should be

```
$("div.app9downloadIcon").tooltip();
```

or simply,

```
$(".app9downloadIcon").tooltip();
```

if no other element has the class `app9downloadIcon`

Comment: maybe that's the prob. I am actually looping through a bunch of stuff and creating multiple `.app9downloadIcon` then attaching the tooltip afterwards.

Comment: So, basically, `$(".app9downloadIcon").tooltip()` will add a tootip to all the elements with this class. If you have multiple `<div>`s with this class and want tooltip on all of them, it is the correct way.